Click button not response during web automation with Python and Selenium 4
I am preparing a web automation system everything is going well but I am stuck at the part in the picture no matter what method I tried it did not work I cannot click the "New Google Ads Account" button I would be very happy if you could help me.
Picture

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep


#Open ADS Login Page
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/ads/")
    
    start_now_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/div/a[1]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", start_now_button)
    
    with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
     credentials = file.readline().split(':')
     email = credentials[0].strip()
     password = credentials[1].strip()
    
    email_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierId"]')))
    email_field.send_keys(email)
    sleep(5)
    
    next_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierNext')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
    sleep(5)
    
    password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')))
    password_field.send_keys(password)
    sleep(5)

    next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passwordNext"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
    sleep(5) 
    
    next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/button/div[3]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
    sleep(5)
    
    # New Google ADS Account
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="mdc-button mdc-button--text new-account-button"]//span[text()="New Google Ads Account"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

I tried many methods such as class name xpath etc. with help from artificial intelligence, but it did not work.

You haven't accounted for the possibility of a cookie notification.
Try this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/ads/")
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.glue-cookie-notification-bar__reject"
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(selector)).click()
    except Exception:
        pass
    selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-g-cta-name="promote-your-channel"]'
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(selector)).click()

Note:
I use CSS selectors in preference to XPATH for 2 reasons. Firstly for speed and secondly if the HTML structure changes the XPATH could become invalid whereas the CSS selector may still work
